# How to get resource path in flask-RESTPlus?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I am fairly new at working with `flask` and `flask-RESTPlus`. I have the following and it is not clear how can I determine which path was used in the get request?

```
ns = api.namespace('sample', description='get stuff')

@ns.route(
    '/resource-settings/<string:address>',
    '/unit-settings/<string:address>',
    '/resource-proposals/<string:address>',
    '/unit-proposals/<string:address>')
@ns.param('address', 'The address to decode')
class Decode(Resource):
    @ns.doc(id='Get the decoded result of a block address')
    def get(self, address):
        # How do I know what get path was called?
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the [request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/). To get the full path, you can do:

```
from flask import request

def get(self, address):
    # How do I know what get path was called?
    print(request.full_path)
```

Comment: Yes, is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Through lot's of digging I found that `url_for` in flask import.

Still feels a bit wonky but I can create a fully qualified link with:

```
result = api.base_url + url_for('resource-settings', address=id)
```

So this works and I get the desired results.